# Mixed model dfbetas procedure question

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, outliers

I have two questions that I will explain in detail and give an example:

1. When iteratively calculating dfbetas in a linear-mixed model and creating a fixed-effect dummy variable to remove the influence of an outlier, is it correct to specify a fixed effect of `0` for the dummy variable (when the outlier-group is excluded and the dummy variable gets kicked from the model)?
2. In order to calculate dfbetas, the estimated covariance matrix of the fixed effects coefficients is needed (for each group that is deleted). So, is it OK to specify all covariances as zero for the dummy variables (when the outlier-group is excluded, and the dummy variable gets kicked from the model)?

**Background**:
A colleague and I are writing up an analysis for a small trial and plan to report the results with and w/out the influence of potential outliers. We wanted to use dfbetas to check for outliers at level-2 (in our case, it is longitudinal data, so this is at the subject-level).

Following the guidance of [Langford and Lewis (1998)](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1467-985X.00094?casa_token=uPlHJzMFUS4AAAAA:ulk_LfTdASBwIl_VnQfHTlXAj9O0uTTKnfItbx5J3QINwsphsHjyIT0-GGikk5IULTqlcblJo11zwUg) and more succinctly stated in [Van der Meer, Te Grotenhuis, and Pelzer (2006)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0003122409359166?casa_token=vCj67USYq78AAAAA%3AqdfrhBSLwkc5wc-phOc5t7-I7y9U6OX8fYPviXjWeo13B75RXm9wmgPi6aGsACSodVRO0m4m51uL&), we identified an outlier and created a fixed-effect dummy variable to remove the influence of the variable (while retaining the subject). I ran into issues checking dfbetas again using `lme4::lmer()` (to create the model), and  the `influence()` method for lme4 `lme4:::influence.merMod()`. The error is expected (below) and I wanted to know my workaround is the best approach (or at least, a reasonable one).

```
# Error message
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
Error in fixed.1[del, ] <- fixef(mod.1) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

*Note*: The error is expected because for the model that excludes the subject with an outlier value has a column with all zeroes (which it drops--first line of the error message), but the fixed effect matrix `fixed.1` includes the dummy variable as a column. So, the function tries to fill a row of `fixed.1` with `ncol(fixed.1) - 1` values. R is understandably unhappy.

**Workarounds**:

Here is the source for [influence.merMod](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/methods.R). First workound, related to the fixed effect matrix, change line 82 in that script to:

```
# line 82: fixed.1[del, ] <- fixef(mod.1)
fixed.1[del, names(fixef(mod.1))] <- fixef(mod.1)
```

Which fills in all columns available as fixed effects (the dummy variable remains `0` only for the model excluding the outlier group). Second workaround, for the covariance matrix of the fixed effect coefficients, change line 90 to:

```
# line 90: vcov.1[[del]] <- vv(mod.1)
vcov.mod1 <- matrix(0, ncol(fixed.1), ncol(fixed.1), dimnames = list(colnames(fixed.1), colnames(fixed.1)))
vv.mod1 <- vv(mod.1)
vcov.mod1[rownames(vv.mod1), colnames(vv.mod1)] <- vv.mod1
vcov.1[[del]] <- vcov.mod1
```

Which fills in the FE cov matrix for all values available (and leaves the dummy variables as `0` for the model excluding the outlier group).

**Summary**:
I am a little out of my depth here, so I could really use some feedback. Are these two workarounds the correct way to check dfbetas in this context / iteratively? (side-note, if these workarounds are tenable, I only have one outlier). Also, please let me know if any other information is helpful. I almost pasted my version of `influence.merMod()` but thought the question was already long enough! Thank you in-advance for any guidance / help!!!

**Example** (if it is helpful):

```
library(lme4)

set.seed(123)
sleepstudy2 <- lme4::sleepstudy

# Creating age variable
subj_age <- tapply(sleepstudy2$Reaction, sleepstudy2$Subject, mean) 
subj_age <- subj_age + rnorm(length(subj_age), 0, 12) # adding noise
sleepstudy2$Age <- round(40 + scale(subj_age[sleepstudy2$Subject])[,1]*10)

sleepstudy2$Age[sleepstudy2$Subject == "310"] <- 50 # creating my outlier
sleepstudy2$Age <- scale(sleepstudy2$Age, scale = FALSE) # mean centering

# Running model
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + Age + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy2)
summary(fm1)

# Checking dfbetas
influence_fm1 <- influence(fm1, "Subject") 
round(dfbetas(influence_fm1), 3) # Subject 310 has age value 4.108 (much greater than threshold)

    (Intercept)   Days    Age
308       0.197 -0.449  0.017
309       0.068  0.310 -0.640
310       0.590  0.158  4.108
330      -0.332  0.279 -0.266
331      -0.260  0.190 -0.219
332       0.004  0.032  0.035
333      -0.118  0.048 -0.112
334      -0.033 -0.064  0.132
335      -0.405  0.556  0.127
337      -0.072 -0.325 -0.459
349       0.233 -0.109 -0.262
350       0.269 -0.345 -0.098
351      -0.115  0.146 -0.011
352      -0.053 -0.112 -0.156
369      -0.050 -0.032  0.032
370       0.398 -0.284 -0.243
371      -0.040  0.046  0.000
372      -0.181 -0.030  0.179


# Create fixed-effect dummy variable
sleepstudy2$dummy_age <- as.integer(sleepstudy2$Subject == "310")

# Running model
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + Age + dummy_age + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy2)
summary(fm2)

# Checking dfbetas
influence_fm2 <- influence(fm2, "Subject") # error
round(dfbetas(influence_fm2), 3) # error

# After workaround:
influence_fm2 <- influence(fm2, "Subject")
round(dfbetas(influence_fm2), 3)
    (Intercept)   Days    Age dummy_age
308       0.333 -0.449  0.088    -0.040
309      -0.225  0.310 -0.395     0.097
310      -0.146  0.158  0.000       Inf
330      -0.274  0.279 -0.070     0.042
331      -0.184  0.190 -0.038     0.021
332       0.147  0.032  0.715    -0.353
333      -0.017  0.048  0.078    -0.042
334      -0.052 -0.064  0.585    -0.127
335      -0.562  0.556  0.074     0.059
337       0.145 -0.325 -0.568     0.215
349       0.216 -0.109 -0.441     0.093
350       0.345 -0.345 -0.092     0.030
351      -0.085  0.146  0.057    -0.058
352       0.088 -0.112 -0.042     0.019
369      -0.021 -0.032  0.039     0.015
370       0.466 -0.284 -0.517     0.144
371      -0.006  0.046  0.012    -0.028
372      -0.162 -0.030  0.412    -0.006
```

Comment: (+1) I realise this doesn't answer the question, hence the comment, but I don't understand the motivation behind this. If the "outlier" is bad data (error), then just remove it. If it's just an extreme observation, retain it.

Comment: @RobertLong, great point! The outlier leans towards an extreme observation but we have a relatively small sample (this data is collected from a small grant) and the outlier has a substantial effect. So, we are going to present data w and w/out the outlier handled for transparency; at least, transparency is our goal. We have separate observational data in the same population (a larger dataset) so we know the outlier-value is very unusual.

Comment: OK. I think you need to explain your study design, your research question(s), give us some more detail about your actual data (sample size etc), and explain what you mean by "the outlier has a substantial effect.". Also, did you do a sample size / power analysis before collecting data ?

Comment: Hey Robert I will add any additional info when I am back at my computer tonight. Trying cover most of it now though: drug intervention, drug given at time0, 25 people, 9 timepoints; powered the study for 2 or 3x the people we have but had to cut off the trial early b/c of funding/covid. Not ideal. As far as substantial, I just mean the dfbetas value is large (>2). Results using the above approach [dfbetas] are almost identical to just excluding the person from the trial. Let me know if I left anything out and thank you for your interest!   Edit: two groups

Answer (score 3):

I think your workaround is a reasonable approach to solve this particular issue; however I strongly advise against this type of procedure. According to the comments to the question, you believe the "outlier" is an extreme observation, rather than an error in data collection. In such circumstances, I would recommend that the main analysis should be the retain this observation with `lmer` and also with `rlmer` from the `robustlmm` package, which fits linear mixed models that are robust to outliers. As a sensitivity analysis, and for transparency (which you rightly mention) you could also report any meaningful differences with `lmer` when the "outlier" is removed (recognising that there is some possibility that it is an error in data collection rather than an extreme value)

Comment: Thanks Robert, for sharing your thoughts. I had not heard of `robustlmm` before and will read more about it!

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so then please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why.

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for following up! It partially answers my question (answers what I am to do for this specific case). I would still like to know more thoughts related to the specifics of the workarounds so I will leave it unanswered for a while. I.e., in the future, if I am identifying outliers (statistical or error-related) for a sensitivity analysis using this method, I want to go about it the correct way.